# High latency of API's

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, latency

We are using Django + gunicorn(sync type) + Nginx + Postgres for development. Currently we log everything into same file. So there are some problems associated with this.

1. As every gunicorn worker is writing into same file, worker is sitting idle for the time in which some other worker is writing to the file(using django loggers).
2. So what happens is after some time number of requests on nginx get queued as no worker is free.
3. So latency is added in 2 stages:-
   a) function latency due to logging
   b) latency due to busy workers. i.e requests get queued on nginx and    are alloted late to workers.

Can somebody help me to get the best solution in this case.Is there something which can write into file asynchronously?

Comment: Is logging everything into a single file really necessary? I don't see any immediate benefits that would outweigh the problems you stated.

Comment: Having individual workers logging to a file is not best practice for this kind of thing - see e.g. https://12factor.net/logs

Comment: @НазарТопольський I think its hard to log things into different file as there is lot of code, I was looking for some solution like writing into file asynchronously.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Its the code that i have inherited, so basically every worker is executing the same code and therefore every worker logging into same file (i mean i am using Django loggers)

Comment: As others have mentioned, it's not best practice. If you're set on doing it this way, your best bet is to play around with [gunicorn's configuration](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes). Failing any improvements, you might want to consider [uWSGI with an async type](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Async.html).